# How to match diacritics with regex within TSQL

Tags: regex, t-sql, diacritics

Regex should allow only characters from a to z, spaces and dash sign (-).

What is wrong with my example script bellow?

```
DECLARE @firstNameRegex VARCHAR(100)='%[^a-z -]%';
DECLARE @firstName VARCHAR(100) = 'Çranko'

IF @firstName LIKE @firstNameRegex
BEGIN
    PRINT 'YES'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'NO'
END
```

Seems like when doing LIKE it converts Ç into C and it pass, but should not.
One more note, COLLATION is set to SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You should use an example the more clearly shows the diacritic

Comment: Like is not regex and ^ is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure range is what is breaking what you want
just put the whole alphabet in

'%[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -]%'

I only test with '%[^cranko -]%' but it worked for me

Comment: It's the same. Makes no difference if I put whole alphabet.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  I tested with cranco and it worked for me.

Comment: When I try with this whole alphabet the above script always return NO, no matter which character i put. For the range it works for some characters e.g. ŠĐČĆ, but doesn't for others e.g. Â, Ã, Ä, Å, Ù, Ú, È, Í, Ó, Õ. Can you check please?

Comment: I don't see the purpose.  If we are not getting the same with even '%[^cranko -]%' then clearly it is an environment thing